# RX Subject add new emit using last value

Tags: javascript, rxjs, frp, subject

I have two subjects: a$ and b$.

```
var a$ = new Rx.Subject();
var b$ = new Rx.Subject();
```

When b$ emits something, need to take this value and add with last emit from a$. Then it needs to send this result to a$.

```
a$ ---4----6------------->
b$ -------------3-------->

result

a$ ---4----6----9-------->
b$ -------------3-------->
```

I can not find a solution to this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can use the `withLatestFrom` operator. For example :

```
b$.withLatestFrom(a$, function (b,a){return a+b})
  .subscribe(function(x){a.onNext(x)})
```

or more succintly :

```
b$.withLatestFrom(a$, function (b,a){return a+b})
  .subscribe(a)
```